# MariaDB Regex Replace only first instance of character

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

```
SELECT REGEXP_Replace('hello', '[l]', '');
```

How do I write my regex to only replace the first instance of 'l'

Answer (score 6):

Use a capturing group with a negated character class and an anchor:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('hello', '^([^l]*)l', '\\1');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qHDoWr/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^l]*)` - [*Capture group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1 capturing 0+ characters other than `l`
- `l` - a literal letter `l` that is just matched and not captured.

The replacement pattern contains a [*backreference*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `\1` that refers to the value contained in Group 1, that is, any text that is not `l` up to the first `l`.

Comment: Can you explain the regex please?

Comment: I added pattern explanation and some links to the regular-expressions.info reference.